# AngularJS Outer ng-repeat not to register watches on inner ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

This is in relation with my question - [Angular JS ng-repeat consumes more browser memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14065050/angular-js-consumes-more-browser-memory)

My problem here is I need nested ng-repeats and the nested ng-repeats consumes more memory because of more watches being registered.

```
<table>
  <thead><td>Id</td><td>Name</td><td>Ratings</td></thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr ng-repeat="user in users | orderBy:'name' | limitTo:display_limit">
    <td>{{user.id}}</td>
    <td>{{user.name}}</td>
    <td><div ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:'rating' | limitTo:inner_display_limit">{{item.rating}}</div></td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here in my case, the number of objects that outer ng-repeat and inner ng-repeat operates on can go upto 1000. And as @Liviu pointed in the answer,`each of the outer ng-repeat registers watch on the inner ng-repeat` and that leads to consumable amount of memory being used. Is there a way we can `avoid the outer ng-repeat from registering watches on inner ones` by writing our own custom directive?

My case is in both inner and outer ng-repeats, I display the initial 50 items and on scroll, if the scroll reaches the end of the corresponding DOM, I update the limit by 50, so that the next 50 items gets displayed.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could write a directive that takes both `users` and `items` as bindings attributes (especially because it seems like your inner loop is independant from the outer one), then manually nest two loops that would add content to the DOM, plus adding a scroll listener to each element. It's more hard-way coding but a lot less watchers.